# Proving that expectation and integration is interchangeable

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am trying to prove that the expectation and integration are interchangeable in the following part of the proof [Link to the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQjyn.png=)
(I am not allowed to embed images yet , sorry)

I tried to apply the Tonelli's theorem but that would require that the function be non-negative. The product here does not seem to always satisfy that so how do I prove the interchange ?

Thanks

Comment: Fubini's theorem?

Comment: Right. I checked the Fubini's theorem. It makes sense. Thanks